# I can't switch "switch to Downloads directory" using bash (I'm new to this)

Tags: files, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new to programming and trying to download Swift on Ubuntu on Windows 10 Insider Preview.

I'm now running bash on Ubuntu, I'm trying to get to the Downloads directory. I tried `cd ~/Downloads` and I get the `no such directory message`. I can't seem to navigate anywhere.

If it helps, When I type `pwd` it says `/root`. When I type `echo $PATH` it shows: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8`

Any help is appreciated, its probably a simple solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: I haven't been able to get the update to have bash on Windows but have you tried `ls` to see the files and tried to navigate that way ... maybe you are in the root directory and there is no Downloads folder there .. maybe its under /home/username .... but I can't be sure because like I say .. I have no way of checking and have never had the chance to play with the new bash in Windows

Comment: trying the update again ... if it doesn't fail this time I may have better information for you in a little while :D

Comment: Ok .. I got bash installed on Windows ... now can you explain how you are "trying to download Swift on Ubuntu" ... what steps are you taking to download the file ... this will help me understand where the issue lies

Comment: What's the output of `echo "$HOME"`? Bash substitutes any occurrence of `~` at the beginning of what seems to be a path name with the value of the environment variable of `HOME`.

Comment: Echo $HOME gives /root

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that you are logged into the Bash shell as root. The beginning of the cursor line should say `your username @ your computer name` not `root @ your computer name` and the end of the cursor should have a `$` not a  `#`. The root account doesn't have a Downloads directory which is why you are getting the error.

If this is the case you can type `exit` and press enter  this should bring you back to where it will have your `username@yourcomputername and the $` at the end. If all else fails you can close Bash and open it again and it should start you in your user's 'home' directory.

Once set this way, typing `cd ~/Downloads` (in Ubuntu/Linux it is case sensitive) will bring you into your Downloads directory. The Bash shell mirrors the Windows drive structure. The downloads folder is the same folder as Windows default download folder ... `C:/Users/yourusername/Downloads`

The original poster was having problems with the bash shell always using root. I have tried everything to get the initial screen back where you enter the Unix user name and password but wasn't able to find a way without breaking the shell.

The way I was able to get back to that initial setting was to create a new Windows account. Log into that account and then reboot

**note** I had to log in and let it set up the account then I had to reboot because some of the files needed for the bash didn't seem to be in place and it seemed to hang when I tried but the reboot solved that.

Then I launched a cmd prompt and type bash to get the following screen. [image]

At this point I screwed up again... I picked the name Don for the UNIX name and put in a password .. everything worked well until I tried `cd ~/Desktop` and it threw an error.

The error said

```
bash: cd: /home/don/Desktop: No such file or directory
```

If you notice in the image the user directory for this account I created is donat not don .. so the ~/Desktop is using the "username" to find the directory

Because of this I would have had to use donat as the Unix name for everything to work properly.

So if you have to create a new account to set this up properly .. Make sure you make note of what directory that new account is using and make that your UNIX login name matches the directory name.

As I said, if I look at explorer  and look at the path C:\Users\ the "Home" folder is donat for this account.

Under further messing around I found that it seems that Windows and the Bash running in Windows doesn't like the `~/directory` shortcuts. You will have to use full paths such as `/mnt/c/Users/username/Downloads` to access your download folder you can't just use `~/Downloads`.

Comment: Thanks John this is all good to know. I'm still having problems though, it may have been with the initial download of bash. I'm only able to run bash through the windows cmd prompt. So I open the cmd prompt and type bash I'm using the root@myPC. And then when I exit I'm back to the regular windows cmd prompt (no bash).

Comment: If you right click on the start menu and choose `Run` then type Bash and press enter do you get the root bash or user bash?

Comment: According to the guide I'm using I should be able to open a "Bash on Ubuntu" command window, but when I search for Bash on my computer I only get a "bash" cmd window.

Comment: I get the root bash. And if I exit from that it closes the window.

Comment: ok you have different issues ... I just opened a cmd prompt and typed bash and pressed enter .. i got the 'user' bash ... I opened a cmd prompt in admin mode  and typed bash and got 'user' bash ... I don't and can't automatically get into root bash  without typing `sudo su` are you logged in as the administrator account and not an "administrators" account .. in other words are you in the default administrator account that is normally disabled in Windows?

Comment: Im assuming that you went into add features and checked the Windows Subsystem for Linux or you probably wouldn't be getting bash at all but it sounds like you are somehow on an account that is considered root. You shouldn't be

Comment: as a test I would create a new user admin account and log into that account .. then try launching bash and see if it shows the user name or is root again ... unless ... this is all just because your user name you chose for your Ubuntu installation was root

Comment: Yes that's what it's supposed to do.. I wonder if I can just try reinstalling bash? I get root when I run cmd as administrator. How do I check which one I'm logged in to?

Comment: When I initially downloaded bash by typing bash I left my computer and came back and it had restarted, so I'm not sure if I missed out on some settings such as setting my user name. Right now I am Administrator. Okay I will try a new user

Comment: first lets see if we are just running around in circles. When you first put in and checked the box for installing the Linux subsystem ... then rebooted and launched it the first time ... it asked  you for a log in name and a password ... did you use root as the login name? or did you give it some other name

Comment: I just logged into my computer as I normally do with my name and password, no root.

Comment: I havent tried a new user so that may work .. but .. I'm looking right now to see how to remove it completely because I can't get back to where its asking me to create the initial login and password .. I tried uninstalling it and putting it back in but it kept the data so if it got messed up on you .. we need to figure out where to remove that information to get you back working properly

Comment: I also only have one account on this computer, so I'm administrator

Comment: yeah sorry you mentioned but i must have been replying already .. that you didn't come up with an option to put in an initial login or password

Comment: Okay I'll work on that

Comment: there is a default administrator account built into windows .. it is kinda the equivalent of root in Linux. It is usually disabled by default and the user account has admin privileges. This was what I was talking about by being administrators ... or the default Administrator account. Sounds like you are just on the normal administrators account so that's probably not the issue .. the issue somehow is you never got the chance to create a default user and password for the bash shell and some how its using root instead

Comment: Yes I believe I'm on the normal user administrator looking at my settings. Exactly I never got to create a pass and user for the bash shell. I have to leave for a couple hours but I will try and reinstall bash when I'm back. Thanks again for your help

Comment: reinstalling wont help .. like I said .. I tried and it kept the same information .. never got a chance to add a user or password ... used the one I originally set up the first time so it did nothing ... I will continue to look to see if I can come up with a solution to add a default user and password.

Comment: Okay perfect, I got it to go to my username (Joel2) from root. However, when I type cd ~/Downloads it doesn't change my directory and I get the same "no such file" message. When I type pwd now I get /home/Joel2.                                                                            The basic steps im using now to get swift are from http://itsfoss.com/use-swift-linux/. I've downloaded the latest files from swift.org and when I type "ls" it shows the file. I'm now back to trying to navigate my directory to downloads or figure out how to extract within the cmd prompt.

Comment: Ok when you downloaded the file .. how did you download it... in a windows browser or through the Bash terminal? sorry .. was rereading this and got a bit confused .. you said you type ls and it shows the file .. where does it show it? the command line should tell you where you are located :/mnt/c/Users/Joel2$

Comment: UM.... sorry new development ... the ~/directory doesn't seem to work properly in the Windows version of Bash. I guess you need to use full paths .. I just tried on the account that was working before and got the same error ... its not mirroring the UNIX home with the Windows Home(Users) directory. so when you type in ~/Download it looks for it in /home/Joel2/Downloads which doesn't exist but should point to the files located in /mnt/c/Users/Joel2/Downloads

Comment: edit: that explains it, thanks I'll try that. edit2: that worked! Thanks.

Comment: yeah i tried a quick and dirty way to try to link the folders so that the /home/Joel2 folder would point to the c/Users/Joel2 folder but that kinda crashed and burned .. it doesn't like the linking :( so .. at least you understand how it works now and how to get around .. basically all your "windows" folder and structure are located at /mnt/c/ .. basically that's like opening a command prompt at the C:> prompt.